# Trying to find whether a categorical (gender) and numeric variable (heart rate) differ between each other while controlling for Age

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, ancova

so I tried to use ANCOVA in R and when I was doing the diagnostics test, turns out the data is not normalized. Now I am stuck, and I do not know where to go from here. Please help. Is there a way that I can normalize my data or is there another test I can do?

Comment: Have you looked at the `scale` function?

Comment: Do you mean normalized or normally distributed? If it is the latter you can also try logging your response variable. My guess, albeit made on little information, would be that you probably want something like `fit <- lm(log(HeartRate) ~ Gender * Age, data = df)` to begin with. I included an interaction to account for differences between gender with Age, although this could be dropped if it is insignificant.